# Multiline hint in TextInputLayout

Tags: android, android-layout, android-textinputlayout

I have a long text which is required to float over edit text as the requirement says. I went through many such question here, but couldn't find the proper answer. How can we make that possible? I have tried using a '\n' with the hint string but it didn't work.

Answer (score -4):

```
you can add \n without giving any space. example shown below

 <string name="hint_manish">Hint first line\nHint second line\nHint third line</string>
```

Comment: can you attached a screenshot for better under standing what you actually want.

Answer (score -4):

The hint takes on the behavior of the Edittext it's related to. 
Adding 
android:inputType="text|textMultiLine"
will give you multiple line hint.

Comment: This is not a solution.

Comment: Why is it not a solution? You should explain to benefit others.